# Linux Samba domain join to auth AD user to SoftEther

Tags: active-directory, samba4, softether

According to SoftEther docs on [authentication using Active Directory](https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/2._SoftEther_VPN_Essential_Architecture/2.2_User_Authentication#Authentication_Using_NT_Domain_Controller_or_Active_Directory_Controller):

> In order to conduct NT domain or Active Directory authentication, the SoftEther VPN Server to conduct user authentication must be capable of running on Windows NT, with capable of participating in domain. SoftEther VPN Servers that run on Windows 98, Windows 98 Second Edition, Windows Millennium Edition or Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris or Macintosh OS X cannot conduct NT domain or Active Directory authentication. VPN Server cannot authenticate the NT domain or Active Directory. In this case, while authentication method is set to “NT domain” or “Active Directory” domain, authentication does not work.

Is it possible to do so on Linux having the server joined to the domain in question or even having it configured as a DC using Samba? Can anyone confirm me right or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this github thread](https://github.com/SoftEtherVPN/SoftEtherVPN/pull/49) the feature may be available in near future, as the code already exists. So the answer for this time is probably **no**, as this update has not yet been merged. You can, however, try to use the patch yourself (and recompile SoftEther) or work this problem around with [RADIUS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755248.aspx).